# does ifstream accept variable file name?

Tags: c++

does ifstream accept variable file name?
I am trying to give a fine as an argument and then will try to read it. What should be the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, of course it does.

```
const char * filename = "abc.txt";

std::ifstream fin(filename);
```

Or using std::string

```
std::string filename = "abc.txt";

std::ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
```

With C++11, you can just use the string directly.

```
std::ifstream fin(filename);
```

Comment: You have a deprecated conversion there, sir.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a character array (which is basically what a string is anyway):

```
char filename[20];

std::cout << "Enter the filename (no more than 20 characters): ";
std::cin >> filename;

std::ifstream inputFile( filename );
```

That should work and allow you to take dynamic user input for your filename.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you pass it as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Give the file name with the file extention

> String var="text.txt"'
>
> ifstream.open(var.c_str(),ios::binary);

Comment: There is no String class in C++. Even if you meant std::string, ifstream.open doesn't take a string as its first argument.

Comment: @Yacoby i know it ! .. im talking abt stf::string